# Getting the height from 4 points and local coords at any given position (walking on a 3d terrain)

Tags: python, python-2.7

On a 3d terrain, i got height information per vertex, and 4 vertexes makes a face, i need to get the height of any point on a face given local (per face) x/y coords and the 4 vertexes z's (in my terrain z is up), i've searched a lot but couldnt find any information about it.

Comment: your vertices define a plane (you only need three of them) insert x and y into that planes equation and you will get z.

Comment: What equation? Btw the vertices are 4, each face is made up of 2 triangles, therefore a square, i dont see why i would need only 3?

Comment: you can have 4 vertices that lie not on the same plane, 3 vertices always lie on a plane therefore define it. you can construct the equation for a plane when you have three points given.

Comment: I see but i still have no clue on how to get the height of a random point on the surface of this plane :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three [non-colinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collinearity) points define a plane. If you have three points `p1`, `p2` and `p3` every point on that plane can be reached from `p1+a*(p2-p1)+b*(p3-p1)`, when you choose the correct values for the two scalar values `a` and `b`. (`p2-p1` and `p3-p1` must be [linearly independant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence)!)

You can also describe a plane by `cx+dy+ez+f=0`. That means if you have given the four scalar values `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` any point with coordinates `x`, `y` and `z` on the plane will give you `0` for the equation `cx+dy+ez+f`. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Describing_a_plane_with_a_point_and_two_vectors_lying_on_it).

You have given the first description of a plane and want to transform it to the second one to get `z` for given `x` and `y`. This is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72938/finding-an-equation-and-parametric-description-given-3-points).

Let `cross` be the cross product `(p2-p1)x(p3-p1)` and `p[0]` be the `x`-value of any vector `p`, `p[1]` be the `y`-value of any vector `p` and `p[2]` be the `z`-value of any vector `p`, then you can solve for `z`:

`z=-(cross[0]*(x-p1[0])+cross[1]*(y-p1[1]))/cross[2]+p1[2]`

If `cross[2]` is `0` you are dividing by `0` here! That case is if your plane is perpendicular to the `x`-`y`-plane. So there are no or infinitly many solutions for any `x`, `y` pair.

Translating the whole thing to python could be done like this:

```
import numpy as np

def get_z(p1, p2, p3, x, y):
    p2_minus_p1 = p2-p1
    p3_minus_p1 = p3-p1

    cross = np.cross(p2_minus_p1, p3_minus_p1, axis=0)

    if np.abs(cross[2]) < 0.00001:
        raise ValueError('plane is perpendicular to x-y plane')

    return -(cross[0]*(x-p1[0])+cross[1]*(y-p1[1]))/cross[2]+p1[2]

if __name__=='__main__':

    p1 = np.array([1., 1., 1.])
    p2 = np.array([0., 1., 0.])
    p3 = np.array([-2., -1., -1.])
    x = 4.0
    y = 2.0

    z = get_z(p1, p2, p3, x, y)

    print(z)
```

Output:

```
3.5
```

So for `p1=[1,1,1]`, `p2=[0,1,0]`, `p3=[-2,-1,-1]`, `x=4` and `y=2` you get `z=3.5`

How you transform from global to local coordinates depends on the definition of your local coordinates.